# Best way to determine conversion rate per product

Tags: conversion

I want to determine the conversion rate per product in a certain time periode. I want to use this in a Magento extension. I am looking for the best way to do this. Most of all it should be reliable in terms of data validity i.e. the conversion rate must be accurate, or close.

- I have been looking into Magento reports models, but I am not sure if this is reliable.
- I have been think about loggin everything myself to my own db table (redundant?) with observers or a js tracking script.
- Using google anylitics to pull data to my extension (overly complex?)

I am still not sure which approach to choose. Maybee another oproach? Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is already on Google Analytics I would just go that route. GA begins sampling data once you hit a very high number of users so if you are looking for exact numbers that *might* be an issue.

Personally I would not bother integrating GA into an extension because it just adds one more extension to maintain over time, but if you have business needs that require you to have a consolidated report, this may be your best option.

You will want to look at goal conversion and ecommerce metrics
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions&jump=ga_goalxxconversionrate

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce